# Create a custom attribute and add it to category grid view Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

On some of my products (not all) I need to add a drop down to select from a list of products (varying depending on product). What is the best way to implement this so it get be chosen next to "add to cart" on the category grid on front end?

Comment: I have added a custom attribute(Name: Warehouse, along with three values) on my sales order grid. if order placed I need able to edit that attribute values, like eg. this order assigned for this warehouse like that. is possible can i edit what i need?

Answer (score 0):

I did this just before few days. You want to show dropdown of `simple` products for any configurable products in category page, right? Check below link it will explain you step-by-step on implementing it. Let me know if you have something different in mind.

http://www.catgento.com/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks @Kalpesh. Where do I set the product as configurable?

Comment: the above link will guide you through. You don't need to code anything beyond that.

Comment: I followed those instructions step by step. where do I enter the options the customer can choose from?

Comment: in a separate configurable_category.phtml, when you're looping for product attributes, it's the dropdown itself that you are looking for.